# If the integral of a function is known, can anything be said about products of integrals of the function and its Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, gaussian-integral, parsevals-identity

Suppose $f \in \mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ is a Schwartz function. Then the Fourier transform is invertible, with nice properties like
$$\int f(x) \overline{\hat g(x)} \mathrm{d} x = \int \hat f(x) \overline{ g(x)} \mathrm{d} x.$$
In physics, if 
$$\hat f(\zeta) = \int f(x)e^{-2\pi i x \zeta}\mathrm{d} x,$$
then $x$ is often called "time" while $\zeta$ is called "frequency". This is very suggestive - I still don't have any intuition for Fourier transforms, but it hints that the variables are somehow inverted.

Suppose $\int|f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x = 1$ and $\int|g(\zeta)|^2\mathrm{d}\zeta = 1$. In general it is certainly not true for arbitrary $\alpha$ that
$$\Big(\int|x|^{\alpha}|f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x\Big)\Big( \int|\zeta|^{\alpha}|g(\zeta)|^2\mathrm{d}\zeta\Big) = 1.$$

However, (noting that the first formula at the top implies $\int|\hat f(\zeta)|^2\mathrm{d}\zeta = 1$), if the two variables correspond to inverses in some sense (as in the Fourier transform), it raises the question of whether or not we can make conclusions about the value of

$$P_\alpha (f) = \Big(\int|x|^{\alpha}|f(x)|^2\mathrm{d}x\Big)\Big( \int|\zeta|^{\alpha}|\hat f(\zeta)|^2\mathrm{d}\zeta\Big).$$

By plugging in the Gaussian for $f(x)$, it is evident that $P_{\alpha}(f) \neq 1$ in general. This made me wonder if we can find bounds - is $P_\alpha (f)$ strictly positive? Is it bounded above? Perhaps we can only draw conclusions when $\alpha$ takes certain values (like 0!) or if our functions satisfy a few more properties.

I figured that $\alpha = 2$ would be the easiest to work with (because it's easy to play around with when using with the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality), but I couldn't prove anything non-trivial.

Comment: for alpha=2 the bound is 1/16pi^2 cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle

Comment: You might want to look at $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x|^\alpha |h_n(x)|^2dx$ for $h_n$ the normalized Hermite functions. For $\alpha \ne 0$ it is always unbounded, the uncertainty principle gives a lower bound.